# std::transform operating till --end() and strange output

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to learn C++11 & STL, and I cannot understand this code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    typedef std::list<int> L;
    L l(5);

    typedef L::const_iterator CI;
    CI cb = l.begin(), ce = l.end();
    typedef L::iterator I;
    I b = l.begin();

    std::transform(cb, --ce, ++b, [] (CI::value_type n) { return ++n; });
    std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::ostream_iterator<CI::value_type>(std::cout));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The array at the end is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and I expected it to be 0, 1, 1, 1, 0

1> Why isn't the last skipped because of "--ce"? I already read the implementation of std::transform and I still don't understand why it wouldn't skip the last: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/algorithm

2> How is it possible that the array in the end is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4? I don't see how that ++n adds up to 2, I thought that since before the values were 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 then it will increment every zero with ++ leading to 0, 1, 1, 1, 0. I see that the first is skipped because of "++b".

Any ideas?

Comment: The key is that output starts at the second element. Then when the input comes to the second it is 1, so the next output will be 2. And so on.

Comment: Not sure what's the confusion, if you can look into code that easily, you could always take a pen and paper to see it why as well.

Comment: usually it is better to pair what P0w said with debugger, since sometimes one can mistaken about code due to tiredness or simple confusion.

Comment: Also, you can use `auto`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to understand this is to write up some iterations of the loop:

**1st iteration:**

```
0 1 0 0 0 
^ input
  ^ output
```

**2nd iteration:**

```
0 1 2 0 0
  ^ input
    ^ output
```

**3rd iteration:**

```
0 1 2 3 0
    ^ input
      ^ output
```

And so on.

It is possible to see then than an element next to the input is incremented.

Also note that `std::distance()` between begin and end of input range (it doesn't include last one) is exactly the same (4) as output range , which is from second element to the last (4).

To illustrate:

Input: indexes 0 1 2 3

Output: indexes 1 2 3 4